# How to I change the size of a storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am learning about iOS app development and I started a project but the size of the storyboard is iPhone 7. How can I make it so that its wider and will be available to all phone sizes?

Like this

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlPf6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS uses size classes and traits. You can create separate layouts for each size class based on the display traits.

When you have the storyboard editor open look at the bottom right in the margins you should se View as: iPhone 7. If you click this it will expand and show you thumbnails of all the devices with one of them highlighted. You can select a different device and make any layout changes and have it apply to that layout only.

See this link for a deeper read: https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/